# Auto Movement Between 2 points issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a question. I have an object that moves unlimited between two points.
For this we used the PingPong method.

```
public Vector3 a;
public Vector3 b;
public float speed;
  void Update()
{
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(a, b, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * speed, 1.0f));
}
```

It all works perfectly, but it is a problem when I try to change the speed directly from the code. So I have another class where I change the speed.

```
 if (index == numIndex + 1 || index == numIndex - 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("Good!");
            other.transform.parent.GetComponent<BadWormsController>().speed -= 0.2f;
        }
        else
            Debug.Log("Bad");
```

The second-order code is executed when the collision occurs between the player and the object moving from point a to point b. 
 It's ok, the speed changes, but the object resets again, so it does not go any further on the axis, but it starts again, so it changes its position.
What is wrong and how to change, if someone has idea, that when changing speed, the object does not change its position, but to continue on.

Comment: I'm guessing that its due to the accumulated value of time. If the item has looped 3 times then changing the speed by 10% will make the object move backwards in time by 30% making it appear to jump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Time.time make a new variable for storing its progress. Then you can adjust this value to negate the difference in position.

```
public Vector3 a;
public Vector3 b;
public float speed;
public float distance;
void Update(){
    distance += Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(a, b, Mathf.PingPong(distance * speed, 1.0f));
}
```

Then when you change the speed you add/remove the difference from the distance

```
// get BadWormsController as var since we use it multiple times
BadWormsController bwc = other.transform.parent.GetComponent<BadWormsController>();
float multiplyer = 0.2f/bwc.speed; // get % of distance to remove
bwc.speed -= 0.2f;  //change speed
bwc.distance -= bwc.distance*miltiplyer; // remove difference
```